# is a diffeomorphism regular?

Tags: diffeomorphism, inverse-function-theorem

I have learned the inverse function theorem which ensures that a regular mapping (which has its inverse) is a (local) diffeomorphism.
But I wonder whether a diffeomorphism is regular.
I guess the answer would be 'yes', but I have no idea.

Comment: what do you mean by a regular mapping?

Comment: its tangent map is 1-1.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you're trying to say. I think it has something to do with the rank of a map

Comment: right. regularity means Jacobian matrix of a map has a full rank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $M$ and $N$ are smooth manifolds and if $F: M \to N$ is a diffeomorphism, then by definition, there is a smooth map $g: N \to M$, such that $f \circ g = I_M$ and $g \circ f = I_N$. Now via chain rule, we get that for every $p \in M$

\begin{equation}
I_{M_{*}} = f_{*} \circ g_{*}: T_{f(p)}(N) \to T_{f(p)}(N)\\
I_{N_{*}} = g_{*} \circ f_{*}: T_p(M) \to T_p(M)
\end{equation}

Where the the '*' denotes the derivative. So $f_*$ is an isomorphism from $T_p(M) $ to $T_{f(p)}(N)$. Since this is true for every $p$, $f_*$ is regular. S

Comment: thank you for help!